# Ploting a point for each step i

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm doing a free fall caluculations (really simple) and would like to plot each instance of height of the objects - that is the height of the object to be displayed as it 'falls' down. I tried running it throught a for loop, but i just get the end result plotted. What would i need to do to dislplay the object as it falls, for each individual - not just the end result.
Here is my code:

```
#Input parameters
y1 = 490 #starting position
y2 = 0 #ground
g = -9.81   #gravity
VY = 0 #starting speed

import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sqrt_part = math.sqrt(VY**2-2*g*(y1-y2))
t1 = - VY - sqrt_part/g
t2 = - VY + sqrt_part/g

if t1 > 0:
    t = t1
else:
    t = t2      
print('t = '  + str(t) + ' ' + 's')    

t_space = np.linspace(0,t,50)
y_t = y1 + VY * t_space + 0.5 * g * t_space**2
v_t = abs(y_t[1:] - y_t[0:-1])/abs(t_space[0:-1] - t_space[1:])

plt.plot(t_space, y_t, 'go')
plt.plot(t_space[1:], v_t, 'r--')

for i in range(np.size(t_space)):
    plt.plot(t_space[i], y_t[i], 'go')
```

The for loop displays the same as the plot above it, but i would like it to update and show the 'ro' as it moves thorught time. How would i do that?
On the left is what i get, on the right is what i want
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BDxN.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, take a look at [matplotlib animation api](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/animation_api.html).

```py
#Input parameters
y1 = 490 #starting position
y2 = 0 #ground
g = -9.81   #gravity
VY = 0 #starting speed

import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sqrt_part = math.sqrt(VY**2-2*g*(y1-y2))
t1 = - VY - sqrt_part/g
t2 = - VY + sqrt_part/g

if t1 > 0:
    t = t1
else:
    t = t2   

print('t = '  + str(t) + ' ' + 's')    

t_space = np.linspace(0,t,50)
y_t = y1 + VY * t_space + 0.5 * g * t_space**2
v_t = np.abs((np.roll(y_t, -1) - y_t) / (np.roll(t_space, -1) - t_space))
v_t = np.roll(v_t, 1)
v_t[0] = 0

from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# create two empty lines
ln_y, = plt.plot([], [], 'go', label="y")
ln_v, = plt.plot([], [], 'r--', label="v")

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(0, max(t_space))
    ax.set_ylim(0, max(y_t))
    ax.set_xlabel("t")
    ax.legend()
    return ln_y, ln_v

def update(i):
    # i represents the index of the slice to use at the current frame
    ln_y.set_data(t_space[:i], y_t[:i])
    ln_v.set_data(t_space[:i], v_t[:i])
    return ln_y, ln_v,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=range(len(v_t)),
                    init_func=init, blit=False, repeat=False)
plt.show()
```